# How can I get timeline data from the profiler?

Tags: symfony

When I open a page of my application in the browser, I can see the debug toolbar at the bottom of the page. When I click on the timeline, however, the data is shown in a canvas.

I'm blind, and thus can't interact with a canvas through my [screen reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader). I'm wondering if there's a way to view the timeline data, without having it drawn on a canvas?